# Change Plotly Boxplot Hover Data

Tags: python, statistics, plotly, visualization, boxplot

I want to change the hover text and hover data for a python plotly boxplot. Instead of 5 separate hover boxes for max, q3, median, q1, and min, I want one condensed hover box for Median, Mean, IQR and date. I have played around with every "hover" variable with no luck. My sample code is found below.

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

lst = [['2020'], ['2021']] 
numbers = [20 , 25]
r = [x for i, j in zip(lst, numbers) for x in i*j]

df = pd.DataFrame(r, columns=['year'])
df['obs'] = np.arange(1,len(df)+1) * np.random.random()

mean = df.groupby('year').mean()[['obs']]
median = df.groupby('year').median()[['obs']]
iqr = df.groupby('year').quantile(0.75)[['obs']] - df.groupby('year').quantile(0.25)[['obs']]

stats = pd.concat([mean,median,iqr], axis=1)
stats.columns = ['Mean','Median','IQR']
tot_df = pd.merge(df,stats, right_index=True, left_on='year', how = 'left')

fig = px.box(tot_df, x="year", y="obs", points=False, hover_data=['year','Mean','Median','IQR'])
fig.show()
```

[image]

In this case I tried to use "hover_data", which does not raise an error, but also does not change the plot, as shown above. I have tried both express and graph_objects with no luck. My plotly versions is 4.9.0. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

- have used technique of overlaying a **bar** trace over **boxplot** trace
- **bar** trace can be configured to show information you want
- for sake of demonstration, I have set **opacity** to `0.05` it can be set to `0` to make it fully invisible
- have built this against **plotly** 5.2.1, have not tested against 4.9.0

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

lst = [['2020'], ['2021']] 
numbers = [20 , 25]
r = [x for i, j in zip(lst, numbers) for x in i*j]

df = pd.DataFrame(r, columns=['year'])
df['obs'] = np.arange(1,len(df)+1) * np.random.random()

mean = df.groupby('year').mean()[['obs']]
median = df.groupby('year').median()[['obs']]
iqr = df.groupby('year').quantile(0.75)[['obs']] - df.groupby('year').quantile(0.25)[['obs']]

stats = pd.concat([mean,median,iqr], axis=1)
stats.columns = ['Mean','Median','IQR']
tot_df = pd.merge(df,stats, right_index=True, left_on='year', how = 'left')

fig = px.box(tot_df, x="year", y="obs", points=False)

fig2 = px.bar(
    tot_df.groupby("year", as_index=False)
    .agg(base=("obs", "min"), bar=("obs", lambda s: s.max() - s.min()))
    .merge(
        tot_df.groupby("year", as_index=False).agg(
            {c: "first" for c in tot_df.columns if c not in ["year", "obs"]}
        ),
        on="year",
    ),
    x="year",
    y="bar",
    base="base",
    hover_data={
        **{c: True for c in tot_df.columns if c not in ["year", "obs"]},
        **{"base": False, "bar": False},
    },
).update_traces(opacity=0.05)

fig.add_traces(fig2.data)
```

[image]

#### `fig2` without named aggregations

```
fig2 = px.bar(
    tot_df.groupby("year", as_index=False)["obs"]
    .apply(lambda s: pd.Series({"base": s.min(), "bar": s.max() - s.min()}))
    .merge(
        tot_df.groupby("year", as_index=False).agg(
            {c: "first" for c in tot_df.columns if c not in ["year", "obs"]}
        ),
        on="year",
    ),
    x="year",
    y="bar",
    base="base",
    hover_data={
        **{c: True for c in tot_df.columns if c not in ["year", "obs"]},
        **{"base": False, "bar": False},
    },
).update_traces(opacity=0.05)
```

Comment: My pandas version is 0.24.2 and therefore, this implementation of named aggregation for groupby does not work. Given, I am not exactly sure what is being constructed for the first argument of px.bar, can you advise how to change this groupby statement to be compatible with pandas 0.24.2? Thank you.

Comment: that's an ancient version of pandas,  named aggregations https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html were introduced in 0.25.  I can't downgrade to 0.24.2 as wheels won't build on my env.  Are you able to upgrade pandas to a version that's less than 2 years old?

Comment: have updated answer with another way of building fig2 without named aggregations.  I can't validate if this works against v. old version of pandas