# Adding counts to Plotly boxplots

Tags: python, plotly, boxplot

I have a relatively simple issue, but cannot find any answer online that addresses it. Starting from a simple boxplot:

```py
import plotly.express as px
 
df = px.data.iris()

fig = px.box(
    df, x='species', y='sepal_length'
)

val_counts = df['species'].value_counts()
```

I would now like to add `val_counts` (in this dataset, 50 for each species) to the plots, preferably on either of the following places:

- On top of the median line
- On top of the max/min line
- Inside the hoverbox

How can I achieve this?

Comment: There is already an answer to this question, but it is an example of customizing a hover template. I understand that your wish is to annotate the boxplot with the count number. Is my understanding correct? If so, I will answer.

Comment: This is indeed correct. While I did not ask for it, a solution that takes into account annotations for grouped boxplots would be very useful to me still (and maybe to others). Based on this Github issue here, there are a few solutions (and an official fix), but only for bar charts:

https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/356

Comment: You said you didn't need an answer, but after reading the comments in the accepted answer, I thought my example might be useful to you. You can use a loop to add the necessary amount of objects as they are added. If you check [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1X5-TmcIWzv_BrwuahscDkEV0kjiBacC8?usp=sharing), it will remove your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The snippet below will set `count = 50` for all unique values of `df['species']` on top of the max line using `fig.add_annotation` like this:

```
for s in df.species.unique():
    fig.add_annotation(x=s,
                       y = df[df['species']==s]['sepal_length'].max(),
                       text = str(len(df[df['species']==s]['species'])),
                       yshift = 10,
                       showarrow = False
                      )
```

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px
 
df = px.data.iris()

fig = px.box(
    df, x='species', y='sepal_length'
)

for s in df.species.unique():
    fig.add_annotation(x=s,
                       y = df[df['species']==s]['sepal_length'].max(),
                       text = str(len(df[df['species']==s]['species'])),
                       yshift = 10,
                       showarrow = False
                      )
f = fig.full_figure_for_development(warn=False)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Quick follow-up question: How would you update the solution for a grouped boxplot (i.e. for 'setosa', if it was split into two boxplots for 'setosa_1' and 'setosa_2', etc.). Is there a way to properly identify the x-axis position in this scenario that as well)?

Answer (score 2):

Using same approach that I presented in this answer: [Change Plotly Boxplot Hover Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68862838/change-plotly-boxplot-hover-data)

- calculate all the measures a box plot calculates plus the additional measure you want **count**
- overlay bar traces over box plot traces so hover has all measures required

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.iris()

# summarize data as per same dimensions as boxplot
df2 = df.groupby("species").agg(
    **{
        m
        if isinstance(m, str)
        else m[0]: ("sepal_length", m if isinstance(m, str) else m[1])
        for m in [
            "max",
            ("q75", lambda s: s.quantile(0.75)),
            "median",
            ("q25", lambda s: s.quantile(0.25)),
            "min",
            "count",
        ]
    }
).reset_index().assign(y=lambda d: d["max"] - d["min"])

# overlay bar over boxplot
px.bar(
    df2,
    x="species",
    y="y",
    base="min",
    hover_data={c:not c in ["y","species"] for c in df2.columns},
    hover_name="species",
).update_traces(opacity=0.1).add_traces(px.box(df, x="species", y="sepal_length").data)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It is not exactly what I was looking for, as the leftover opacity is a  bit confusing for a publication, but I will keep it in mind nonetheless as a possibility.

Comment: one thing you can do is reduce impact of bar by reducing it's height.  I've made it cover whole box plot, it can be use a **base** just below median and **y** that places it just above median.  happy to share if it helps