# Plotly express box plot hover data not working

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, plotly-express

Trying to add data to hover of boxplot express in plotly and following the instructions [here](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.express.box.html) in plotly 5.4.1. It is mentioned in the tutorial that additional information to be shown in the hover can be added by `hover_data` and `hover_name` argument. However, The additional hover data, in this case information from `continent` column, is not presented in the hover. I am not sure what is going wrong here? (Here is the code I test in Google colab)

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1234)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(20, 1),columns=['Col1'])
df['country']=['canada','france']*10
df['continent']=['america','europe']*10

fig = px.box(df, x="country", y="Col1",  hover_data=['continent'])

fig.show()
```

Here is what i get in google colab:

[image: plotly boxplot in google colab]

Error I get with suggested solution (this was solved with `pip install plotly --upgrade`):
[image]

The solution offered by @Rob works but to make it a generic function, here is what I wrote out of it:

```
def box_with_hover(df,x,y,hover_data):    
  fig = px.box(df, x=x, y=y, hover_data=[hover_data])

  fig.add_traces(
      px.bar(
          df.groupby([x, hover_data], as_index=False).agg(
              base=(y, "min"), y=(y, lambda s: s.max() - s.min())
          ),
          x=x,
          base="base",
          y="y",
          hover_data={hover_data:True, x:True, "base":False, "y":False},
      )
      .update_traces(opacity=0.1)
      .data   ).update_layout(bargap=0.8)


  fig.show()
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. When you hover your mouse over the boxes, it will show the data.

Comment: @morhc, continent data is shown?! are you testing it on google colab? could you share screen shot please? thanks

Comment: It's the same result that you have in your screenshot. Is this not the data that you want -- if so please clarify the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- this is similar to [Change Plotly Boxplot Hover Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68862838/change-plotly-boxplot-hover-data)
- **boxplot** hover info is within javascript layer of **plotly**. Hence have overlayed a **bar** plot where hover can be controlled in way you require.  When you hover over **boxplot** you get standard **boxplot** hover.  **bar** different hover info

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1234)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(20, 1), columns=["Col1"])
df["country"] = ["canada", "france"] * 10
df["continent"] = ["america", "europe"] * 10

fig = px.box(df, x="country", y="Col1", hover_data=["continent"])

fig.add_traces(
    px.bar(
        df.groupby(["country", "continent"], as_index=False).agg(
            base=("Col1", "min"), y=("Col1", lambda s: s.max() - s.min())
        ),
        x="country",
        base="base",
        y="y",
        hover_data={"continent":True, "country":True, "base":False, "y":False},
    )
    .update_traces(opacity=0.1)
    .data
).update_layout(bargap=0.8)


fig
```

[image]

#### generic function

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1234)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(20, 1), columns=["Col1"])
df["country"] = ["canada", "france"] * 10
df["continent"] = ["america", "europe"] * 10
df["letter"] = list("AB") * 10


def box_with_hover(*args, **kwargs):
    if isinstance(args[0], pd.DataFrame):
        kwargs["data_frame"] = args[0]
    fig = px.box(**kwargs)

    fig.add_traces(
        px.bar(
            kwargs["data_frame"]
            .groupby([kwargs["x"]], as_index=False)
            .agg(
                **{
                    **{
                        "base": (kwargs["y"], "min"),
                        "y": (kwargs["y"], lambda s: s.max() - s.min()),
                    },
                    **{c: (c, "first") for c in kwargs["hover_data"]},
                }
            ),
            x=kwargs["x"],
            base="base",
            y="y",
            hover_data={
                **{c: True for c in kwargs["hover_data"]},
                **{kwargs["x"]: True, "base": False, "y": False},
            },
        )
        .update_traces(opacity=0.1)
        .data
    ).update_layout(bargap=0.8)
    return fig


box_with_hover(
    df.reset_index(), x="country", y="Col1", hover_data=["continent", "letter", "index"]
)
```

Comment: Thanks @rob. I get this error with this solution bar() got an unexpected keyword argument 'base'

Comment: I'm using plotly 5.4.0, pandas 1.3.4.  are you getting that error with exactly code I put in answer? `df.groupby(["country", "continent"], as_index=False).agg(
            base=("Col1", "min"), y=("Col1", lambda s: s.max() - s.min())
        )` does this work?   I'm suspecting a pandas version issue with named aggregations

Comment: I updated plotly and pandas version in google colab with : pip install plotly==5.4.0 and pip install pandas==1.3.4. I added the plot of error in the question.

Comment: would it be possible for you to check this in google colab?

Comment: it works in Colab, just need to run `pip install plotly --upgrade` first and restart runtime

Comment: Yes, the upgrade solves the problem. This is a bit complicated way. Can we write a function out of this? I can give it a try but was wondering is there any reason there is no function for it out there yet? Thanks @Rob

Comment: I've attempted to code up as a generic function.  just coding, but I definitely have not managed all edge cases